# Auto-place a featured image after x amount of paragraphs in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm currently using [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) with WordPress. The requirement is for me to be able to place an image - uploaded in Types- after every 2 paragraphs.

Now, I know how to pull in the field from Types. What I'm not sure about, (perhaps this is done with Javascript?) is how to then auto-place one image after 2 paragraphs, then another image after 4, etc.

Is this possible? My very limited jQuery knowledge informs me it might have something to do with an nth-child selector or something? But this is just a guess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/tkK6y/

Let's say you have an array of image URLS:

```
var imgs = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'];
```

And a div with `n` paragraphs:

```
<div id="theDiv">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Bar</p>
    ...
</div>
```

You can loop through every second paragraph and insert images after each one like this:

```
var $div = $('#theDiv');
var $paragraphs = $('p:nth-child(2n)', $div);
var n = 0;
$paragraphs.each(function () {
    var $newImage = $('<img src="' + imgs[n] + '" />'); // Creates an img tag
    $newImage.insertAfter(this);  // Inserts the img after the current paragraph
    n++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do this without jquery, only using php and the would be to do a custom loop where you would define a incrementing variable and you would display a result every other post using a basic math function like so:

```
$x = 1; while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if (($x % 2) == 1 && $x != 1)   {
// Display your custom image here
}

$x++; endwhile;
```

Comment: This displays an image after every second *post*, not *paragraph*.